# opengl android movement with given speed

Tags: android, opengl-es

This is a very basic issue, but I just can't find a complete answer anywhere.

Consider an object is moving along the z axis with a given SPEED. (Ex: -0.2 opengl units)
Now I rotate the object around its local axis with rotationX , Y and Z angles.

Question: what is the next position of my object?

I am using the following equations (which I know are wrong, but I just can't make them right)

```
    positionX += -SPEED * Math.sin(rotationY * Utils.DEG)* Math.cos(rotationX * Utils.DEG);
    positionY += SPEED * Math.sin(rotationX * Utils.DEG);       
    positionZ += -SPEED * Math.cos(rotationX * Utils.DEG)* Math.cos(rotationY * Utils.DEG);
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I would store a vector that represents the orientation of the object.

On rotation, rotate the orientation vector.

When moving,

```
positionX += SPEED * orientation.X
positionY += SPEED * orientation.Y
etc.
```

Comment: I also tried with vectors, but I am in the same situation. I have problems when multipling with the rotation matrices. So I guess either solution would be just fine, as long as you would explain in more detail.

Comment: @Mihaisiatat - Please post your code for the vector rotation, and explain what problems you are having.